# Is that possible use cob_people package on Ros Kinetic with Ubuntu 16?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is that possible use cob_people package on Ros Kinetic with Ubuntu 16 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268806/is-that-possible-use-cob_people-package-on-ros-kinetic-with-ubuntu-16-?/) by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2017-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the README of the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ipa-rmb/cob_people_perception) it says that Kinetic is supported.

**Edit:** the [original repo](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_people_perception) shows that Kinetic is supported.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-15**:
@jayess: you are linking to a fork of the repository.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-15**:
@gvdhoorn, I found it through the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_people_detection). Is that still not the correct one?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-15**:
No, seems you're right, it is the correct fork. I'm just not used to IPA / cob pkgs being hosted on personal accounts.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-15**:
Yeah, seems weird so I put both in the answer.

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2017-08-15**:
ı will try it thank you

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-15**:
@Developer: If this was the correct answer, please mark it as so.